# Dataflow Pipeline Follows Notebook Execution Number. Cant Update Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to update my dataflow pipeline. I like developing using Jupyter notebooks on Google Cloud. However, I've run into this error when trying to update:
"The new job is missing steps [5]: read/Read."

[image: Data Flow Console]

I understand the reason is because I re-ran some lines in my notebook and added some new lines, so now instead of "[5]: read/Read" it is now "[23]: read/Read" but surely dataflow doesn't need to care about the jupyter notebook execution. Is there some sort of way to turn it off and just call the steps using the given names without the numbers?

[image]

Comment: Additionally to the correct answer accepted below: all the transforms applied by re-execution are incrementally added to the pipeline. So if you have never re-executed the line `p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(),options=options)`, you will see all transforms such as "[5]: read" and "[23]: read" both present in the pipeline. In that way, you will not run into the missing transform issue, but you do waste resources running extra old transforms on Dataflow. So always "restarting the kernel and rerunning all cells" before starting a Dataflow job is the cost efficient way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Notebooks [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/interactive-pipeline-development#launching_jobs_from_a_pipeline_created_in_your_notebook) recommends restarting the kernel and rerunning all cells to avoid that behavior.

"(Optional) Before using your notebook to run Dataflow jobs, restart the kernel, rerun all cells, and verify the output. If you skip this step, hidden states in the notebook might affect the job graph in the pipeline object."

Doing so will preserve the numbers.